# Delete a list in txt file which are older than today's date

Tags: c#, text

My C# program has a function which appends this lists in a program real-time. My program is return a list of values date, name and status.

Do you have any idea how to append only the list with the latest time?

This is my C# code

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("rn_agent.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 
           + Environment.NewLine 
           +  name 
           + Environment.NewLine + status + Environment.NewLine);
```

**rn_agent.txt**

```
2022-05-26 13:57:29
Dannie Delos Alas
Available
2022-05-26 13:57:29
Krishian Santos
Available
2022-05-26 13:57:29
Puja Pal
Unavailable
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Maricar De Mesa
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Pula Al
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Marjorie Cacayan
Unavailable
```

Comment: Can you provide expected output? What do you mean by `append only the list with the **latest time?**`

Comment: `2022-05-27 14:43:42
Maricar Tayag
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Puja Pal
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Marjorie Agravio
Unavailable`


just example only. if 2022-05-27 14:43:42 is the lates time. that list that has time on it should be only in the text file

Comment: I believe you want to re-write the file instead of appending text to it? is that what you want? Like remove all old entries and write latest data into the file

Comment: I am appending the text because i have some realtime values that automatic append to textfile. but I think rewriting the text file solves everything.

Comment: Caution: re-writing the text file will **lead into loss of past data**. If it is fine for you then go ahead and use `File.WriteAllText()` instead of `File.AppendAllText()` method

Comment: You should not use `{DateTime.Now` on every line you append.  Initiate a variable with that value once, and use that variable every time you want to append a line to your text file.  this will make sure all DateTime values are the same.

Comment: Ive tried this. correct me im wrong     var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            var newText = $"{date} \n {name} \n {status} \n";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_) method instead of [`File.AppendAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-appendalltext(system-string-system-string)), to write latest data into the file.

```
var newText = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} \n {name} \n {statu} \n";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("rn_agent.txt",newText);
```

---

##### What is difference between File.WriteAllText() and File.AppendAllText()?

***[File.WriteAllText():](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_)***

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, **it is overwritten.**

***[File.AppendAllText():](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0#system-io-file-appendalltext(system-string-system-string))***

> Opens a file, **appends the specified string to the file**, and then closes the file.

---

**Update:**

If you want to store all the records which available for today then try below code,

```
var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var newTextList = new List<string>();

//Dummy foreach loop
foreach(var data in agentsData)
{
   newTextList.Add($"{today} \n {data.Name} \n {data.Status}");
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("rn_agent.txt", newTextList);
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I think that solves it. however when I use File.WriteAllText It only gives me the last list of output which is 2022-05-27 14:43:42
Marjorie Agravio
Unavailable   instead of 2022-05-27 14:43:42
Maricar Tayag
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Puja Pal
Occupied
2022-05-27 14:43:42
Marjorie Agravio
Unavailable.

Comment: Did you check @Luuk's comment, as he said you need to save `DateTime.Now` value to some variable to keep it same for all your data. If you use same date time value, it will resolve above issue

Comment: Can you add more code which include if..else condition which where it decides to wirte a data to a file or not? BTW if my answer helped you to solve your query then don't forget to accept it by ✔

Comment: var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            var newText = $"{date} \n {name} \n {status} \n";

Is this what @Luuk's meant. ive tried this and its not working. correct me.thanks

Comment: You should store at the top before for/foreach loop which iterate and gives you details like name, status...

Comment: ive tried it sir ,it does not work. do you have any other idea sir

Comment: You can try storing only date with default time that too into the variable.

Comment: Im trying the thing that youve posted sir. I cant add var newTextList = new List<string>(); because of my declared code here  List<string[]> chat_agents = rn_chat.GetStatus();.
I apologize , im still a beginner.

Comment: @LemFajarda, I guess we are digressing from our main topic now. I helped you as much as I can. If you still have doubts, first it is better to debug by your own. If still you can not proceed then write a new question with specific details, minimal reproducible example. You can check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details to write a good question

Comment: Id like to thank you for all your help. I think I can debug it on my own. Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: I've finally got the output I needed, thanks to you!